# x86 assembly: Declaring a nested array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, x86

I am new to x86 assembly, and am having trouble finding resources on nested arrays and what they would look like when declared with something in c like: `long arr[5][10];`. Can anyone provide a little insight into what the assembly would translate to? Thanks.

Edit: Over a year and a half later, I understand how this question was very trivial as an array in memory. In this case an array of 50 longs would just be an allocated block of 50 * 8 = 400 bytes (Assuming that the sizeof(long) = 8). Something like this in x86_64 asm could translate to `sub rsp, 400`.

However, that example only applies to a local array, where globally it may be in a .data or .bss segment like:

```
section .bss
arr resq 50
```

Comment: There is no concept of arrays in assembly - just raw memory. You allocate some memory (on the stack or the heap) and write data to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try looking at compiler output?  (https://godbolt.org/ / [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output)).

**Bytes are just bytes**; the assembler doesn't know or care how the instructions in your program are going to use them.

If this is at global scope, normally something like GAS `.section .bss` ; `.zero  4*5*10` which is exactly identical to `.zero 200` to reserve 200 bytes in the BSS.  Or `.comm arr, 200` to do the same thing without switching sections.  There are many synonyms for `.zero` / `.space` and so on to fill bytes, see [the GAS manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Pseudo-Ops.html).

Or in NASM, `resd 5*10` in `section .bss`.  Or of course `resq` if your `long` is 64-bit.

As a local variable, that would just be part of the space reserved on the stack.

Assembly doesn't have types in the same sense that C does, so `long arr[5][10]` is just a chunk of 200 or 400 bytes of memory, same as `char arr[200]` or `long arr[5*10]`.  C integer types are a compile-time thing, influencing which instructions the compiler uses to access the data.